# Tell a regex expression to skip the beginning of a line before matching

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

If I had a string like `45mb   ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd` and I use a regex like `[^\/]*\/` it will match `45mb   ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/`

I only want it to match `./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/` but I can't figure out how to do it.

I want to specifically match/find all occurrences of "everything before a forward slash up to and including the slash" as I want to use `sed` to substitute the matches like in the below `sed` command but not losing the file size bit at the start.

```
sed -e 's/[^\/]*\//--/g
```

Hopefully that makes some sense. I tried look ahead/behinds but I don't know if that's the correct regex solution for this.

Comment: Is the format always `filesize {space} filename`? Maybe `awk` would suffice? `|awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: If you just want to exclude spaces add that: `[^\/ ]`.  What is your ultimate goal?  It sounds like you are doing some tricky filename parsing / formatting, and usually that's never a clean and easy task.

Answer (score 1):

Since you clarified what you wanted in a comment to Gnouc's answer, here's a solution:

```
sed 's|[^ /]*/|--|g'

$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd' | sed 's|[^ /]*/|--|g'
45mb --------dddd
```

This will break if you have a trailing slash, or if the filepath you're passing to it contains any spaces. It would be pretty easy to script something a little more watertight, but it would involve more than a single line.

---

Here's one solution using capture groups:

```
sed -e 's|\([^ ]* \).*/\(.*\)|\1\2|'
```

I'm using `|`s as the separators because then I don't have to bother escaping the forward-slashes (but I would have to escape any `|`s in the pattern). AFAIK `sed` can have pretty much any character as a separator.

The first capture group `\([^ ]* \)` matches 'any number of any character except a blank space, followed by a blank space'. The `.*/` matches 'any number of any characters, followed by a forward-slash', and the second group `\(.*\)` captures 'any number of any characters'.

Sed's regular expressions (and most regular expressions) are greedy by default, so `.*/` will match the longest string that matches its pattern.

```
$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd' | sed 's|\([^ ]* \).*/\(.*\)|\1\2|'
45mb dddd
```

However, this will break if there is a trailing slash:

```
$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/' | sed 's|\([^ ]* \).*/\(.*\)|\1\2|'
45mb
```

This version *will* work even with a trailing slash, but will break if you have more than one:

```
sed -e 's|\([^ ]* \).*/\(.\)|\1\2|'

$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/' | sed 's|\([^ ]* \).*/\(.\)|\1\2|'
45mb dddd/
$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd//' | sed 's|\([^ ]* \).*/\(.\)|\1\2|'
45mb /
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using regex with perl:

```
$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd' | perl -ne 'print $1 if /(\.\/.*\/)/'
./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/
```

And substitution:

```
$ echo '45mb ./aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd' | perl -ple 's/(\.\/.*\/)/--/'
45mb --dddd
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers but i dont think i explained the end goal well enough.

I want to run `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print0 | xargs -0 du -h --max-depth 1 | sed -e 's/[^\/]*\//--/g;'` 

to print a dir hierarchy with depth represented by -- for every sub-folder and at the start i want the dir size.

At the moment the find and du will print what i want, and the sed will replace the dirs with -- but it also chops off the dir size from the start which i want left intact.

Comment: .. turns out sed doesn't support regex lookarounds so thats why i couldnt get it working. Accepting answer from Gnouc for perl example. 

The end solution was `perl -ple 's/(?<=\/)[^\/]+\//--/g'`

thanks again